How to fix runtime error in Android studio
I am working on a project in Android Studio when I ran into an issue where it kept crashing when I attempted to run it on a real device. It worked perfectly fine at first, however as I used viewBinding, it stopped working and crashed immediately.
This is the Runtime error that I keep getting
2024-04-05 11:11:36.978  9368-9368  AndroidRuntime          usap64                               E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.login_act, PID: 9368
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.login_act/com.example.login_act.MainActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.example.login_act.MainActivity> cannot be instantiated
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3737)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4022)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2336)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8653)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.example.login_act.MainActivity> cannot be instantiated
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
                                                                                                        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:44)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1253)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3725)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4022) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2336) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8653) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130) 
2024-04-05 11:11:37.042  4589-4614  WindowManager           system_server                        E  win=Window{3a9cc03 u0 Splash Screen com.example.login_act EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=true win.mRemoveOnExit=true win.mViewVisibility=0 caller=com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:5251 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:5232 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onExitAnimationDone:5654 com.android.server.wm.-$$Lambda$01bPtngJg5AqEoOWfW3rWfV7MH4.accept:2 java.util.ArrayList.forEach:1262 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.onAnimationFinished:7162 com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.doAnimationFinished:2626 


This is my MainActivity.kt
abstract class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() , View.OnClickListener {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val username = binding.usernameTxt
        val password = binding.passwordTxt
        val login_btn = binding.LoginBtn

        login_btn.setOnClickListener {

        }
        when{
            TextUtils.isEmpty(username.text.toString()) ->{
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Please enter your username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            TextUtils.isEmpty(password.text.toString()) ->{
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Pleas enter your password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            username.toString() != "admin123" && password.toString() != "adminpass123" ->{
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Invalid Username and/or Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            else ->{
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Logging in....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
}

This is my activity_main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="199dp"
        android:layout_height="244dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#2E2727"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/avatar" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username_Txt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#100A0A"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/username"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textColorHint="#0B0909"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password_Txt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#050505"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textColorHint="#0B0909"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/username_Txt" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/LoginBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#DAD8D8"
        android:text="@string/Login_btn"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password_Txt" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:text="@string/forgot_pass"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textColorHint="#020202"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/LoginBtn" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


You're missing part of the exception from the trace.  Your activity can't be instantiated, but why it can't would be in the wrapped exception you didn't post.

@GabeSechan Can you check it again, I already edited the exception part.

Is there a reason why your question is tagged as [tag:java] when no Java code is involved?

@Edric you're right, I just removed the tag.

Your MainActivity is declared as abstract, hence Android (and everyone else really) is unable to instantiate it.
If you really need it to be abstract, try subclassing MainActivity and declare the child in your AndroidManifest.xml. Would be good to also give a different name to the parent class.
e.g.
parent:
abstract class BaseActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
 ...
}

child:
class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {

}

